# Eliminar elemento duplicado junto con el elemento que se duplica PHP

Tags: php, array

Tengo un array en php que me devuelve una lista de elementos en los que puede haber repetidos. Necesito eliminar los repetidos junto con el elemento en cuestión.

```
Array=[1,2,3,4,1]
ArrayNuevo=[2,3,4]
```

Probé con la función:

```
array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Pero no me elimina el elemento que se repitió. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Idealmente coloca parte del código funcional de lo que intentaste, en tu respuesta, para ver como lo intentaste. Eso ayudara a hacer una mejor respuesta y no solo obtendrás una solución sino que sabrás donde te has equivocado.

Answer (score 3):

La función array_unique elimina la repetición de elementos de un array, pero siempre se queda con el primer valor que has introducido.

Desconozco si existe una función en PHP que realice exactamente lo que necesitas, por lo que te recomiendo que proceses tú mismo el array. Existen infinidad de maneras de hacerlo pero, te adjunto una rápida que se me ha ocurrido:

```
    $arrayOriginal  = [1,2,3,4,1, 'string'];
    $arrayProcesada = [];

    $arrayTemporal  = array_count_values($arrayOriginal);

    foreach ($arrayTemporal as $key => $element){
        if($element == 1){
            $arrayProcesada[] =  $key;
        }
    }

    var_dump($arrayProcesada); // array[2,3,4, 'string']
```

Si hicieras un var_dump de $arrayTemporal recibirías el siguiente array, donde cada una de las keys son el value de $arrayOrignial y el value de estas es el número de repeticiones dentro del $arrayOriginial.

```
array:4 [
  1 => 2
  2 => 1
  3 => 1
  4 => 1
  'string' => 1
]
```

Comment: La respuesta está bien, solo que no existe la función `dump` en el ámbito del código o de la librería estándar de PHP. Posiblemente quisiste decir [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: Correcto, gracias por la puntualización, he modificado la respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta , me oriento muchisimo y ya lo consegui!. Gracias comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

No existe ninguna función nativa en php que realice la eliminación completa del elemento duplicado.

Como indicas [array_unique](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) elimina los valores duplicados de un array (evitando que duplicidades), pero mantiene el valor que creo la duplicación.

Para eliminar tanto la duplicidad como el valor que creo la duplicidad necesitamos jugar un poco con el array para detectar los valores duplicados y eliminarlos por completo.

Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

// Array de entrada
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1];

// Contar el numero de apariciones de cada valor
$counts= array_count_values($array);
print_r($counts); // Array ([1] => 2, [2] => 1, [3] => 1, [4] => 1)

// filtrar aquellos valores que aparezcan solo una vez
$countsFiltered = array_filter($counts, fn($c) => $c === 1);
print_r($countsFiltered); // Array ([2] => 1, [3] => 1, [4] => 1)

// obtener las keys que son los valores originales, pero ya filtrado
$result = array_keys($countsFiltered);

print_r($result); // Array ([0] => 2, [1] => 3, [2] => 4)
```

Documentación:

- [array_count_values](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php): Cuenta todos los valores iguales de un array
- [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter): Filtra elementos de un array usando una función
- [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-keys): Devuelve todas las claves de un array